# Wordpress Pods: Unable to query multiple pod types trough pods API

Tags: wordpress, podscms

So the case is I have a event-pod and a newsitem-pod.
I would like to query them so i have a combined list of pods of type event/newsitem:

```
$params = array( 
 'orderby' => 't.name DESC'
);

//i know 'events + news' is not correct notation, but it's to give the idea :)
$mypod = pods( events + news, $params );
```

the reason why i want them trough the 'pods' api is, so i can handle the media items like i would with every other pod.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Any reason you can't use a standard WP_Query? Unless you're using pods tables you should be able to get away with a standard query, which has no problem pulling in data from multiple types.

Comment: i thought of that too.. But is there a way to cast the WP_query to an instance of the pods class?  since i would like to work trough the pods API.

Or would you recommend to stick with WP syntax?